# How to fix "Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/dependencies/ContextElementDependency'" in angular2 and .net core application.!

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, web-deployment

[You can click here to view a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT3Gd.png) I'm developing a new web application using .net core and angular2, it's my first code using both methodologies, I'm having the following error, how to solve it.!

```
"Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/dependencies/ContextElementDependency'
"
```

I've already tried to reinstall npm and webpack package.
I've delete the (package-lock.json) file.

```
includes my packages.json :

    {
      "name": "STS_InternalRequests",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
        "build": "ng build --extract-css",
        "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
        "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
        "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "arrive": "2.3.1",
        "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "express": "4.15.3",
        "jquery": "1.12.4",
        "moment": "2.18.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
        "ngbootbox": "0.2.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "~1.7.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/ngbootbox": "0.0.29",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "typescript": "~2.5.3"
      },
      "optionalDependencies": {
        "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
      }
    }
```

I expect the code to run successfully.

Comment: Can you show us some additional information? As an image of the error screen or the error log itself?

Comment: @CaioLadislau I've updated my question, you can follow the link to view the image :)

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8315#issuecomment-341817481

Comment: @CaioLadislau thank you, already tried, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Update es2016 to es2017 in my root tsconfig.json file fixed this issue

```
],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts","src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

and then run the following commands

```
 rm -rf node_modules
 rm package-lock.json 
 npm cache verify npm install
```

if this not help then run 
remove webpack from DevDependencies in Package.json

```
rm node_modules/ (remove node_modules folder)
rm package-lock.json (remove package-lock.json file)
npm install -g webpack (install webpack globally)
npm install -g webpack-dev-server
npm install
```